# Gorm golang sql.NullInt64 not working when we wrapper with another struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

User can be deleted by another user. In that case,

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email string `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    DeletedBy     sql.NullInt64
}
```

DeletedBy will be null when we create a new user. So I used sql.NullInt64 instead of int64.
But I cannot convert to JSON.

> { "Email": "xxxxx",
>   "DeletedBy":
>   {"Int64":2,"Valid":true}
>   }

For that, I tried https://gist.github.com/smagch/bc34f861df65c8ea2e90
But Gorm send query condition value as **"[{2, true}]"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go when you declare a type as an *alias* of another type, the new type **does not get to keep** the other type's methods. So here:

```
type NullInt64 sql.NullInt64
```

your new `NullInt64` type has the same structure and memory layout as `sql.NullInt64` **but** it does not have its methods, namely the [Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64.Scan) and [Value](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64.Value) methods required for it to work the way you want.

Instead what you can do is to embed the `sql.NullInt64` and you should be good to go.

```
type NullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}
```